# Avoid horizontal scroll HTML web page

Tags: html, css

My website is primeauth.com and I have an issue. Just scroll to the right, it goes right away. I think there's some issue with the position or something.

Kindly help me with putting it like normal website like a box.

Kindly help!

Comment: Usually, it's some element's margin or padding that causes the problem, but without knowing the code I can only make guesses right now... If you set **`overflow-x: hidden`** to the body it will likely alleviate it without requiring further 'digging'.

Comment: There is a problem with the carousel you have added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have content moving "*out of the box*" at the `#testimonials` `<section>`.

You should use the `overflow` property to this *container* :

```
#testimonials {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

`overflow-x` is for horizontal.
`overflow-y` is for vertical.
without axis, this will set for both.
[MDN - overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)
You could apply this property to the `body` too but applying it to the container of your slider is a proper way to do it.

Comment: Did you mean `#testimonials`? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to the "People are already section"

```
section.no-overflow{
          overflow-x: hidden;
                }
```

[image]